# How to compute $\int_C \frac{z^4}{z^5-z-1}$ where $C$ is the radius $2$ circle centred at $(0,0)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Apparently, because all the finite poles are within the circle, it is good enough to use the residue at infinity. But I'm not sure how to even show all the roots are bounded in norm by 2.

Comment: How about Rouche's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Rouche's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RouchesTheorem.html): on $\;|z|=2\;$ , we have that $\;|z+1|<|z^5|\;$ , so both $\;z^5\;$ and $\;z^5-z-1\;$ have the same number of roots in $\;|z|<2\;$ .

Define now $\;f(z):=\cfrac{z^4}{z^5-z-1}\;$ , and let now $\;z_k\;,\;\;k=1,2,3,4,5\;$ ,  be a root of our quintic, then as all these roots are simple we get that

$$Res_{z=z_k}(f)=\lim_{z\to z_k}(z-z_k)f(z)=\lim_{z\to z_k}\frac{z^4}{5z^4-1}=\frac{z_k^4}{5z_k^4-1}$$

Before going into this, you may want to observe that the roots of $\;z^5-z-1\;$ are: one real root and two pairs of complex non-real *conjugate* roots.

Comment: The residue computation and the distinction between real and non-real roots are actually irrelevant for evaluating the given integral.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Perhaps, yet to avoid doing calculations on residues at infinity, which apparently posed some problem to the OP, the above could possibly help...

Comment: of course it is a viable strategy, but I think it is easier to notice that $f(z)$ is very close to $\frac{1}{z}$ if $|z|$ is pretty large.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, indeed: it's way easier in fact to work out even with the very residue at infinity. I really don't understand well how you accomplised your last equality $\;=o(1)\;$ . I would have directly go with the residue at zero of $\;-\frac1{z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right)\;$ ... DO you have any reference?

Comment: It is pretty simple, indeed: $f(z)-\frac{1}{z}=O\left(\frac{1}{|z|^5}\right)$, hence by integrating $f(z)-\frac{1}{z}$ over the circle $|z|=R$ we get something that is $o(1)$ for $R\to +\infty$. $O\left(\frac{1}{R^4}\right)$, actually.

Answer (score 3):

**Step1**: all the roots of $z^5-z-1$ are simple and lie inside the region $\left|z\right|\leq\frac{3}{2}$.
The roots are simple because $\gcd(z^5-z-1,5z^4-1)=1$, and they lie in the region $\left|z\right|\leq\frac{3}{2}$ because if $\left|z\right|=C>\frac{3}{2}$, $\left|z\right|^5 > |z|+1 \geq |z+1|$ contradicts $z^5=z+1$.

**Step2**: by Cauchy's theorem, the given integral equals $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of the function $f(z)=\frac{z^4}{z^5-z-1}$, that also equals $\oint_{|z|=R}f(z)\,dz$ for *any* $R>\frac{3}{2}$. However:

$$ \oint_{|z|=R} f(z)\,dz - \oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{z} = o(1) $$
for $R\to +\infty$, hence the given integral simply equals $\color{red}{2\pi i}$. This happen because for any $z$ far from the origin $f(z)-\frac{1}{z}=O\left(\frac{1}{|z|^5}\right)$, hence by integrating $f(z)-\frac{1}{z}$ over the circle $|z|=R$ we get something that is $o(1)$ for $R\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let$$g(z)=\frac{5z^4-1}{z^5-z-1}\text{, let }h(z)=\frac1{z^5-z-1}.$$ and let $r$ be the greatest absolute value of the roots of $z^5-z-1$. Then $f=\frac{g+h}5$ and therefore $\int_Cf=\frac15\bigl(\int_Cg+\int_Ch\bigr)$. By the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle), and because $r<2$, $\int_Cg=5\times2\pi i=10\pi i$. On the other hand, if $R>r$, then the integral of $h$ along the circle of radius $R$ around $0$ does not depend on $R$. Furthermore, its limit when $R\to\infty$ is equal to $0$. Therefore$$\int_Cf=\frac{\int_Cg+\int_Ch}5=\frac{10\pi i+0}5=\color{red}{2\pi i}.$$